# Transaction Management while performing Functional Testing Spring Rest Interface

Tags: spring, rest, functional-testing

I am trying to write a Functional Testing suite. The test utilizes a bunch of Rest calls to execute workflows (The testing is black-box testing, using the rest interface.). The application under rest is Spring 3 and uses Spring's transaction management(DataSourceTransactionManager). To avoid individual setup and tear-down methods, I was thinking of making the transaction rollback-able.This is accomplished by using @TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true) when doing unit\integration testing, but I am not aware of a straight forward way of doing it, while performing integration testing(since they are individual rest calls).

The application under test is not single threaded and multiple concurrent testing suite might be running at the same time on the same database instance\application.

My preliminary analysis leads me to believe that I should force spring to use the same rollback-able transaction for all the methods in a test suite.(Like using a Factory method that returns a Transaction based on a unique identifier. Passing a unique request parameter and using AOP to somehow inject a transaction for this thread)

Have any of you done anything similar. I would really appreciate some ideas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Good Question,

I am planning to use transaction in my Junit test too

Please use if  the following works for you

```
@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback(true)
```

It will take some time for me to implement this in my project but hope, this will help you before I need this.

One more thing which i read is the program is multithreaded.

Do you  not wish to use the Isolation  level which are provided by spring ? But I  think  it will be developers who should take care of this.